# Did the Crisis of the late Middle Ages cause a notable expansion of wilderness in Europe?

Tags: middle-ages, europe, demography, depopulation

There was a lot of wild forest in the early Middle Ages, around 75% in the 9th century [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medieval_demography#:%7E:text=Most%20medieval%20settlements%20remained%20small,of%20Europe%20was%20still%20forested), much of which was cleared during the population boom in the [High Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Middle_Ages). I also read on Wikipedia that in the late Middle Ages the European population possibly dropped by half due to the events sometimes collectively known as the [Crisis of the Late Middle Ages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_of_the_late_Middle_Ages#:%7E:text=The%20Great%20Famine%20of%201315,regain%20the%20levels%20of%201300) ([Black Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death), [Great Famine of 1315-1317](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Famine_of_1315%E2%80%931317) and the [Little Ice Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ice_Age)), with the population not replenishing to pre-crisis levels for some centuries.

Although I found a number of sources<sup>cite needed</sup> talking about the ramifications of the population decline, I couldn't find anything specifically about the land, and whether or not there was any notable return of farmed/cleared land to wilderness or forest after the population decline, including agricultural land, pasture, or managed woodland.

Comment: It doesn't take too long for a forest to claim former farming fields.  I have a friend who bought acreage in western New York.  When he bought it, it was all forest.  But he found a photo of the property from the 1890s, and it was all farming fields and an apple orchard.  He cut his way into the forest and found the old apple trees, too - still there.

Comment: Lots of research on this topic available. See, for example, Nature: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41559-021-01652-4#:~:text=The%20uniform%20~50%25%20mortality%20postulated,regions%20of%20western%20Europe56.

Comment: What definition do you use for wilderness?

Comment: @JonCuster Interesting, it shows still an increase of population in the eastern parts of the Holy Roman Empire.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you speak German, you might want to look for terms like [Wüstung](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCstung) or, more specifically, Flurwüstung. The short version is that (in Germany) there definitely were quite a number of villages and even towns that were given up in the 14th/15th century.

In some cases, the fields and meadows continued to be used as fields and meadows, in others they eventually turned into forests. Opinions vary on whether German forests are really wilderness, though.

Comment: Isn't that when the famous fairy tales in dark forests (Hansel & Gretel, etc.) emerged?

Comment: @Jos "emerged" in which sense?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава fairy tales have to start somewhere or are based on something. I know that many fairy tales involving cannibalism originate in or after the 30 years war. I wouldn't be surprised some are even older.

Comment: @Jos Many are deemed to be thousands of years old, actually.

Comment: @Jos But for Hansel and Gretel there are indeed hypotheses that "the tale emerged in the Late Middle Ages Germany" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hansel_and_Gretel , whatever "emerged" means here.

Comment: Any reference to that last sentence? Not doubting you, but I'd like to learn more on that topic (and it is kind of expected to reference non-trivial assertions here, but mostly I just want to educate myself).

Comment: @T.E.D The source (which I would have to look again first) said something very close to "usage is forest is land usage too", which I admit I extrapolated a bit from.

Comment: @T.E.D. Almost certainly the larger forests were wilderness. Forests were used as resources to feed animals and gather mushrooms and wood, but I think it is safe to assume that all such usage was within hiking distance, or near (the few) roads. Larger forests must have been impassable, vast, lonesome, frightening places.

Comment: @T.E.D. it is right in the [wikipedia article](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/W%C3%BCstung#Flurw%C3%BCstungen) where it discusses problems with the definition of abandoned land: "Auch die Wiederbewaldung bedeutet kein Ende menschlichen Wirtschaftens."